# What is the origin of "earthling"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, suffixes

- What is the origin of the word *earthling*?
- Are there other words with a similar meaning (*marsling*, *venusling*)?

Comment: The demonyms for Mars and Venus are Martian and Venusian (the latter is not to be confused with Venetian.)

Comment: For more on Venus, see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153668/what-is-the-adjective-corresponding-to-venus

Comment: Obviously, it's the term the Martians used when they visited Sector 51.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As reported on [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=earthling):

> Old English *yrþling* "plowman" (see *earth* + *-ling*); the sense of "inhabitant of the earth" is from 1590s. *Earthman* was originally (1860) "a demon who lives in the earth;" science fiction sense of "inhabitant of the planet Earth" first attested 1949 in writing of Robert Heinlein. Earlier in this sense was *earthite* (1825).

However, I found this too:

> Ælfric (955–1020)
>   ***Teacher***:hwæt sægest þu **yrþlingc** hu begæst þu weorc þin

Comment: "Earthite" sounds like a mineral, perhaps a hard clay. Any way to find the 16th-century source?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: OED: Thomas Nashe · *Christs teares ouer Ierusalem* · 1st edition, 1593 (1 vol.). Wee (of all earthlings) are Gods vtmost subiects.

Answer (score 11):

The word [earthling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthling) is formed from the word *earth* and the suffix *-ling*, meaning something from earth, or something related to earth. Here *earth* can either refer to the planet, or to the soil.

It's now mostly used in science fiction to mean humans from earth, but it existed even before that. One older use is in the meaning of *farmer* or *ploughman*, another is in the meaning of *mortal* as contrast to heavenly creatures or gods.

In science fiction the term *Terran* is also commonly used.

Answer (score 3):

NOAD gives for “-ling”:

1. forming nouns from nouns, adjectives, and verbs (such as hireling, youngling).
2. forming nouns from adjectives and adverbs (such as darling, sibling, underling).
3. forming diminutive words : gosling | sapling.
   • often with depreciatory reference : princeling

This gives you some more examples...

Comment: When I asked if there are other words like _earthling_, I meant words like _marsling_, or _venusling_.

Answer (score 2):

Origins are well covered.  Another synonym is *Earther*.

Answer (score 2):

'Earthling', before the sci-fi era, had somewhat the same connotations as 'troglodyte', an lesser, earthy person (see the [etymonline provenance](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=earthling) as in mplungjan's answer). This is what probably inspired Heinlein to use it to have people not from Earth refer to people from Earth. The sci-fi literature has created a number of alternatives, like 'earther' and 'terran'. 'Earthling' has too much of a 1950's scifi connotation and is not used in contemporary sci-fi, except for pejoratively.

As to other planets, generally recognized inhabitant names, though having only imaginary referents, are:

- Venusian
- Martian
- Jovian
- Saturnian

'Mercurial','venereal', 'martial', jovial, and 'saturnine' are the respective metaphorical versions (that is, not referring to an inhabitant, but to 'slippery/fickle', 'sex-related', 'military-like', 'convivial', and 'gloomy', respectively). 'Earthy' would be the closest analog for Earth.

The other planets don't really have commonly recognized inhabitant names, but they can be easily created anew: Mercutian, Uranian, Neptunian, Plutonian (yes, I know... then Erisian, Cerean, Haumean, Makemakean...).