# What is the adjective corresponding to Venus?

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct adjective corresponding to the noun Venus?

Comment: For all planets see ["What is the origin of Earthling?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11465/what-is-the-origin-of-earthling)

Answer (score 8):

Venus is both a planet and the Roman goddess of love and sex. Adjectival forms therefore have two separate uses: for the planet, and in medicine to describe things like sexually transmitted diseases.

"Venusian" is by far the most common adjective in use for the planet among professional astronomers. Some classically minded writers dislike "Venusian" because it doesn't resemble Latin forms such as "Veneri." "Venerian" was 
used by some 20th-century science fiction writers such as Robert Heinlein and Jown W. Campbell, Jr. It also appears to have been used sometimes as an adjectival form of Venice (George Finlay, History of Greece Under Othoman & Venerian Domination). "Cytherean" is sometimes used, referring to the island Cythera, near which the goddess was supposed to be have been born. A search of astronomy papers on arxiv.org, however, shows that "Venusian" is nearly universal.

In medicine, the most common term is "venereal," which is closer to being a legitimate Latin form than "venusian." There are also "veneric" and "venerean."

Comment: Very good. The proper name in the more culturally respectable genres is *venereal*, I believe, even though this form does not exist in Latin (**venerealis*). But it is clear from the Latin that it must begin with *vener-*, the adjectives used in Latin being *Venereus* and *Venerius*, and *venereal* is a English regular formation based on the Latin stem *Vener-* of the word *Venus.*

Answer (score -1):

Some adjectives for Venus is boring,bright,glorious,hot,lonely.These reasons are some of the answer because there is nothing to their because their is no life and obviously no internet  but seriously their is nothing to do their to explore only dust and rocks.I think the sun is glorious because it has beautiful ring around Venus.Venus is bright because the glistering blazing sun shines on the rings that reflect the light around Venus.Venus is hot because of course it is the second planet next to the sun.It is going to be lonely out in Venus because like i said their is no living life up their so you wont make any friends but if you are really crazy go ahead make friends with rocks!!

By a 6th Grader kid Lucas

Comment: IS it ok tell me now Tigers from macarthur!

Comment: opps i got confuse with Venus and Saturn